# Key event not fired when opening a view as sheet (or modal)

Tags: swift, macos, modal-dialog, keyevent

I have a view controller with some controls (listview, buttons, etc.) called "ListaViewController"  where I capture key events with this code:

```
override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        
        if keyIsDown == true {
            return
        }
        keyIsDown = true
        if event.keyCode == 36  && abiertaLista == true && ventana == "Lista" { 
             //do something
        }
}
```

I have another viewcontroller called SettingsViewController which I open from a button in the first controller with this code

```
self.presentAsSheet(BorrarViewController)
```

if I don't open the second controller, the capture key events function works well in the first controller, but if I open the second as sheet (or modal) and close it, then the capture event function is not fired in the first controller.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Update:

The process is like this I have a main controller, the init controller, called ViewController (as per default), which has a keyevent handler logic, then with a button I open ListaViewController which also have a keyEvent handler logic. When I try to open and close any alert or viewcontroller as modal or sheet, then in ListaviewController the keyevent handler fires nothing.

I´m sorry, but I deleted the button that load the alert or viewcontroller and its code (rage is bad...)

To clarify, in ViewController I have another code to handle the keyevents :

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    
    override var acceptsFirstResponder: Bool { return true }
    ///Lots of more code
}
```

Comment: WHY ARE WE YELLING?!

Comment: Tittle fixed, sorry

Comment: How do you close the sheet?

Comment: I think the issue is that your key events are being delivered to your `BorrarViewController` when it's open, and not your `ListaViewController` (which would no longer be the first responder). I would introduce a coordinator class, and make both VCs delegate to it, by making their `keyDown` events call a common method on the coordinator, which could be the central key-handling logic for this area of the UI.

Comment: @Alexander the `BorrarViewController` is closed.

Comment: The key event handle logic is made in ListaViewController, BorrarViewController has no key event logic. I close the BorrarViewControler with:
 
self.dismiss(self)

By the way, i tried with this code in the BorrarViewController CloseButton :

if let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "ListaView") as? ListaViewController {
            abiertaLista = true
            cuentaPrincipio += 1
            
            self.view.window?.contentViewController = controller
         }

And it works, but it loads again ListaViewController...

Comment: @Willeke Oh I see.

Comment: @PabloJiménezRevilla What is the first responder at the moment after your `BorrarViewController` is closed?

Comment: @Aleksander i really dont know. Wich should be?? Im not too good with first responder handling

Comment: @PabloJiménezRevilla IDK, check it. That's why I'm asking :p

Comment: ok, i tried to know with: print("ES: \(view.window?.firstResponder)"), and before opening the BorrarViewController it prints: Optional(<NSTableView: 0x1012ac0f0>)

It prints the same when i close BorrarViewController

Comment: @Aleksander Any ideas?

Comment: I tried your code but I can't reproduce the issue. Post a [mre] please.

Comment: @Willeke do you mean a video???? because if not i would have to make a new project... but i have mine on github https://github.com/pablormago/RetroMac

Can i send you a PM??

Edited: i can´t find a way to PM you, i´ll try to update my question with my code

Comment: No, not a video, just enough information the reproduce the issue. I'll take a look at the github code.

Comment: I deleted the way i open a modal alert or viewcontroller, and it´s not in github, sorry...

Answer (score 0):

OK. So i removed this line in the view.willAppear :

```
self.view.window?.styleMask = [.borderless]
```

and it worked... don´t know why but it works now...

Comment: Could you please elaborate in more details how your question and your answer are connected to each other? Specifically, in the answer you're referencing some code being edited, which was not mentioned in the question.